# Apply effects/filters to more than just image objects in FabricJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I've been using FabricJS for a while now for my interactive comic builder and for the most part, it's been great. A limitation however is that - to date - I haven't been able to find any way to make objects that aren't images apply effects.

For instance, [this guide](http://fabricjs.com/image-filters) shows how to render effects over an image object but let's say for example, I wanted to apply the effect to shapes like rectangles and circles drawn with Fabric or text objects. Is there a way to do this already?

I'm not too interested in presets such as sepia or vintage etc, I really only need the ability to blur, lighten/darken and saturate/unsaturate.

Comment: If you like my answer, please consider selecting it. I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not clear about how <kbd>fabric.js</kbd> works. I have looked through their site and noticed that it is only meant to be applied to images. Since you would like to apply these filters to other elements, I will share with the CSS <kbd>filter</kbd> attribute.

### Javascript

To say that the variable `element` is equal to the element that you are trying to apply filters to, here is how to apply filters with JavaScript.

```js
element.style.filter= "blur(8px)";
```

### CSS

To say that the element has an `id` of `element`, use CSS to achieve the following.

```css
#element {
    filter: blur(8px);
}
```

There are lots of filters that are possible. To learn more about how to use them, click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp)!

### Example:

```css
p {
  filter: blur(5px);
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
p:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<h3>Put Your Mouse Over The Element Below:</h3>
<p>Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text, Text</p>
```

Comment: That's great and all but how would that work with FabricJS? The way Fabric handles elements is a lot more complex than just using HTML tags so using CSS wouldn't really make much sense for this. Example of checking for element: https://prnt.sc/vyrsa9

Comment: @Venk, If it is all inside a `<canvas>` element, don't worry, you can use javascript from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter). It is how to do those effects on elements inside the canvas.